# How to force string variable to evaluate to hex char in a string?

Tags: php, string, hex, evaluation

I am trying to represent a character by its hex value inside a string. It works if hex is explicit but does not work when hex variable is used:

```
$hex = '5A';
echo "Hex explicit: \x5A, Hex evaluated: \x$hex";
```

The output is:

```
Hex explicit: Z, Hex evaluated: \x5A
```

The question is - how do I modify `\x$hex` to get Z instead of `\x5A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

Integer literals

```
<?php
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
?>
```

This is the answer

```
$hex = chr(0x5A);
echo "Hex explicit: \x5A, Hex evaluated:".$hex;
```

or

```
$hex = chr(0x5A);
echo "Hex explicit: \x5A, Hex evaluated: $hex";
```

Try this link
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_chr.asp

Comment: How can I use it to get `Z` in my example?

Comment: Thanks, that works! Just be careful with w3schools - [http://www.w3fools.com/](http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: why is that? It would be great if you have something better than w3.

Comment: W3schools are not bad for beginners but consider these [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link)

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev can you up-vote my answer, since you have accepted it as the best answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it appears already downvoted (perhaps when the answer was considered not helpful). I could probably do it if you write a new answer.